# selenium send_keys() Message: element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os, time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\carlo\OneDrive\Escritorio\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

time.sleep(10)

name = 'me'

user = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))[0]
user.click()

msj_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_2FbwG"]')
msj_box.send_keys('la caja')
msj_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="_1U1xa"]')
msj_box.click()
```

This got probleman when is running the following line

```
msj_box.send_keys('la caja')
```

And the output is this

```
 File "c:/Users/carlo/OneDrive/Escritorio/wp3.py", line 23, in <module>
    msj_box.send_keys('la caja')
  File "C:\MIS programas\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\MIS programas\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute 
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\MIS programas\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute   
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\MIS programas\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

It seems the reason you are getting the error is because you are using the method SendKeys with a Div element rather than to an input or text area.

```
msj_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_2FbwG"]')
```

Comment: I meet a case that when I edit value in the input area, the class is look like this, 1111 is what I enter. <div class="ChatMessageInputView_growWrap__mX_pX" data-replicated-value="1111"><textarea class="ChatMessageInputView_textInput__Aervw" placeholder="Type a message..."></textarea></div>  ..... however, I cannot send_keys